# ubuntu: can't install sdl1.2-dev due to broken packages

Tags: lubuntu, sdl

I tried to install `libsd1.2-dev`, but got an error due to some dependencies that I do not know how to solve.

```
sudo apt-get -f install libsdl1.2-dev 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                      libglu-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My `uname -a` is:

`Linux moon 3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 19:56:49 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Running Lubuntu-Desktop. Installed is `libsdl1.2-debian` (version 1.2.15-5ubuntu1)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have it already install synaptic package manager. Now under edit click `fix broken packages` and follow  the instructions (I am not sure what they are since I don't have broken packages). Afterward you should probably hit apply and you should be OK.

Comment: Of course, I had tried this. When I select libsdl1.2-dev to be installed I get the red exclamation mark and when I try to install it, Synaptics says that I have to fix the broken package first. If I then choose "fix broken package" I get:
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem. I had unselected the "source" option in the repository settings ... silly me. Thanks Wouter !!